# Equal cor values in mtcars dataset?

Tags: r, correlation

When I run the following piece of code in R :

```
print(cor(mtcars[,c(1,5)]),method="kendall")
```

I always get the same result as :

```
       mpg      drat
mpg  1.0000000 0.6811719
drat 0.6811719 1.0000000
```

irrespective of whether I set :

```
method="kendall" or "spearman" or "pearson"
```

Is it a coincidence that all the three correlation tests give same correlation coefficients for mtcars dataset in R or am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you use the `method` argument for `print`, not `cor` (i.e., a typo):

```
cor(mtcars[, c(1, 5)], method = "pearson")[1, 2]
# [1] 0.6811719
cor(mtcars[, c(1, 5)], method = "kendall")[1, 2]
# [1] 0.4645488
cor(mtcars[, c(1, 5)], method = "spearman")[1, 2]
# [1] 0.6514555
```

and

```
print(cor(mtcars[, c(1, 5)], method = "kendall"))
#            mpg      drat
# mpg  1.0000000 0.4645488
# drat 0.4645488 1.0000000
```

Comment: Questions with a typo should be closed, not answered, and it was for this very reason. If anything, you should make this a comment, not an answer.